# How to handle insert rules in multisite environment?

Tags: multisite, rules-engine

I've got some insert rules defined for my website, now I have to convert this into a multi site solution. My current insert rules apply to the new site. How can I restrict insert rules to work only on a single site in multi site environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create site-specific rules for insert options in /sitecore/System/Settings/Rules/Insert Options/Rules

For each rule you can select a condition (for a site-specific rule it would probably be 'where the item is the specific item or one of its descendants' for your site root) and an action (adding/removing specific insert options).

If you want to have custom rules per site and add them under each site node you could create site-specific folders with rules and override the default uiGetMasters/runrules processor with a custom class.

**Links**:

Site Specific Insert Option Rules For Sitecore
https://www.markstiles.net/blog/2013/1/18/site-specific-insert-option-rules-for-sitecore/

All About Insert Options in the Sitecore ASP.NET CMS
https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/all-about-insert-options-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Insert Rules using Rule Magic
https://trayek.wordpress.com/2013/05/24/insert-rules-using-rules-magic/